# Finding the maximum value of $7t -11 - 2t^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, maxima-minima

I am to determine the highest possible value of $p(t)$ when

$$p(t) = 7t - 11 - 2t^2$$

I try completing the square:

$$= -2\left(t^2 -\frac{7}{2}t + \frac{11}{2}\right)$$

$$= -2\left(\left(t-\frac{7}{4}\right)^2 - \frac{49}{16} + \frac{11}{2}\right)$$

$$= -2\left(\left(t-\frac{7}{4}\right)^2 + \frac{39}{16}\right)$$

But I have no idea where to go next.

Comment: The highest value of $t$, or of $p(t)$? For the latter, think about the squared term in your final expression. What values can it take, and which of these would make a maximum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the whole thing is multiplied by $-2$, meaning that it'll be largest when what's inside the bracket is *smallest* (since "smaller" negative numbers are in fact larger). So we want to minimize

$$(t-\frac 7 4)^2+\frac{39}{16}$$

By picking a certain $t$. The $\frac{39}{16}$ doesn't change with $t$, so it won't affect our minimization. We can throw it out. So we've reduced the problem to minimizing

$$(t-\frac 7 4)^2$$

which is simple: squares are always positive (or zero), so the smallest value this can take is zero. And it takes this value only when $t=\frac{7}{4}$. So the function takes its largest value at $t=\frac 7 4$. Plugging this into the function will give you the maximum value that the function takes.

Answer (score 0):

Complete the square:
$7t - 11 - 2t^2 = -2(t-\frac{7}4)^2-\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

You can also differentiate the expression, with respect to $t$ in order to obtain the maxima
$$d((p(t))/dt=-4t+7$$
Now, we equate this to zero,
$$-4t+7=0$$
Which gives us,
$$t=7/4$$
If you do not know calculus you can use the result that, the value of maxima must be equal to
$$-D/4A$$
Where, D is the discriminant and A the leading coefficient, it would yield the very same result.